# How do I throw a custom error that specifies what field needs to be filled out

Tags: python, html, django

How do I specify what field needs to be filled out when giving an error in django. Right now the error is just "this field is required," but how do I change this field into the actual field like password, or username or something. So instead of the normal error: "This field is required" it should give: "Password is required or Email is required," based of the field.

Here is the code for the errors:

```
            {% if form.errors %}
                {% for field in form %}
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <p class=" label label-danger">
                    <div style="text-align: center">
                     {{ error }}
                    </div>
                </p>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
```

Comment: Usually you would render the field's errors next to the field, any reason you don't want to do this?

Comment: Saying that, you have the field since you are accessing its errors. Could you not not have `{{ field.label }}: {{ error }}`?

Comment: This is close to what I want but I only want it for the required error and I also want it to replace "this field" in "this field is required."

Comment: Is this a form that you have defined yourself?

Comment: override the error message, look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#error-messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the required error message by [passing `error_messages` to the field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#error-messages)

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    some_field = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Some field is required'})
```